# Can connect to database using mysqli, but cannot get even the simplest query to execute

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

I am a pretty unskilled programmer, but I had put together a functioning search engine using MySQL, but am now exploring MySQLi, to see how to get the search engine to work using MySQLi instead. I know I am connecting to the database, since I have run successful connection tests, but I cannot get even the simplest queries, cut & pasted, and altered only to reflect the name of my own table, fields, etc, to execute. I have tried four or five different MySQLi query examples I've found online, altered them, and never get anything but a blank page back! In this example, I just duplicated a query example from YouTuber mmtuts (before that I tried other examples from W3schools, etc), altering it to reflect the name of my table, fields, etc, and I get a blank page back. What am I missing? Btw I am using Bluehost (switched to them from another host recently), and I don't know if there is some Wordpress factor going on (I hardly understand what Wordpress is) - but I have run successful connection tests on Bluehost, so I don't expect that's the problem. This example breaks the connection code and query code into two separate documents:

First document (searchtmysqli2.php):

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "xxxx";
$dbPassword = "xxxxx";
$dbName = "xxxx";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

?>
```

Second document:

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/searchtmysqli2.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records;";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo $row['Artist'];
        }
    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect` deprecated func

Comment: in your `searchtmysqli2.php` script, is it `mysql_connect` or `mysqli_connect` ?

Comment: PS. do not display the credentials, I have edited those.

Comment: oh good call - ok let me edit that - somehow missed that.

Comment: Ok, still does not work with mysql_connect changed to mysqli_connect. Sorry @user5173426, I don't understand what you mean by 'do not display the credentials.'

Comment: Please do not change your question with the suggested edits as it makes hard for the new readers.

Comment: @supthepunks Whenever you post something public like on Stackoverflow, you really should not paste some database or server credentials (username and password) as there are ugly souls out there who may use those to log into you machine and use it as theirs.

Comment: @feeela - Thanks for looking out! Those are made up though.

Comment: @user5173426 - Sorry, I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: `echo $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);` and what do you see?

Comment: @user5173426 - If I replace     echo $row['Artist']; with that code, I still get a blank page (assuming that's what you mean). (Sorry, I don't know how to format the code section of this comment).

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code below, and also add the global  variable global $con; to your function as per below and then test ....

THE TOP OF THE DOCUMENT SHOULD LOOK LIKE THIS

```
<?php
    include_once 'includes/searchtmysqli2.php';

    $con = mysqli_connect("YOUR_HOST","YOUR_USERNAME","YOUR_PASSWORD","YOUUR_DB");
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo"
                Failed to connect to the MySQL DB:".mysqli_connect_error();
            }

?>
```

THEN EDIT YOUR FUNCTION TO LOOK LIKE THIS

```
<?php
    global $con;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records";
    $results = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

    if ($resultCheck > 0) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
             echo "<li>$row['Artist']</li>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying this out.

Comment: So, sorry, but are you saying to include all the above code in a single document? And also, I think you are saying to edit the code, rather than add this to it, correct? And thirdly, shouldn't the $conn in the php section also be changed to $ global con?

Comment: add the connection string to the top of the document just after the include statement... and then add the "global $con" to the top of the function as shown... btw you declare the variable $results, but then refer to $result in the $resultCheck declaration, and in the "if" statement

Comment: one more thing. Do not terminate your SQL statement with a semicolon...."SELECT * FROM records;" this should be "SELECT * FROM records" .i.e. no " ; "

Comment: Man, still getting a blank page. Thanks a lot for your help, evenso.

Comment: About that semi-colon - in the video he specifically talks about why you should use that semi-colon (the explanation went over my head). I am going to try it without now, though.

Comment: Removing the semicolon did not seem to help.

Comment: about the semicolon you should check this         https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248766/terminating-semicolon-in-php-mysqli-discouraged...For debugging  I would try adding some print statements at this point ,,, also try adding an else statement after the if to echo some simple string for example and see if it displays on the page

Comment: ok made one more edit for you to try see in answer i.e.  echo "<li>$row['Artist']</li>"

Comment: That did not seem to help. I am getting this error in the error log: "syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file in [name of file] on line 31" - line 31 is the one with </body> on it. Cannot figure out what it's referring to, though. oh, wait...

Comment: GOT IT! It wasn't that - it was that the function php tag wasn't closed! Thank you so much for your help!